# Can there be a min/max for a set with cardinality of $1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I want to know, mathematically, can a set $S = \{55\}, |S| = 1$ have a min and max?

Is it that, $$\min(S)=\max(S)=55.$$
Is this okay?

I don't know if minima and/or maxima even exists/defined in such a case
as cardinality is $1$, thus, no elements for comparision.

Comment: Yes.  Your condition of comparison applies when needed.

Comment: Yes, and this is also why constant functions have the same minimum and maximum. Can you see why?

Comment: Yes.  It is true.  We don't really care about the other elements we can and can compare the maximum element to, so much as we care that we have an element that is equal or large to every element (including itself).  It may not agree with standard english but, hey, standard english doesn't agree with math.  That is to say, we *could* define a quasi-maximum element that is larger than all others other than itself if there are any.  Such a concept would agree with english, but... what the heck would be the point of that?

Comment: tl;dr.  The definition of max compares the element with *every* element in the set, not merely to the *other* elements in the set so it does compare it to itself.  And as we can compare the element to itself it doesn't matter if there are no others to compare.  $\max S = x$ (if it exists) so that $x \in S$ and for all $y\in S, x \ge y$.  If $S=\{55\}$ then for all $y \in S$ (that is to say for $y =55$) we *DO* have $55 \ge y$ because $55\ge 55$.  So ... that satisfies *everything* in the definition of $\max$.

Answer (score 1):

$(S, \le ) $ be a partial ordered set. Then for $A\subset S$ , an element  $m\in S$ is called greatest element of $A$ if $m\in A$ and $a\le m$ for all $a\in A$ which are comparable to $m$.

For linear ordered sets any two elements are comparable.

Given $S=\{55\}$ . Claim $55$ is the greatest element of $S$.$(s\in S\implies s\le 55)$ True!

Other way:

Suppose $55$ is not the greatest element of $S$.Then $\exists s\in S $ such that $s>55$ . Does such $s\in S$ exists?

Note : Here $a>b$ means $b\le a$ but $b\neq a$ .